# What is Margu saying?

Tags: klaus

In the movie Klaus from Netflix there is a sámi girl called Margu that speaks in a language that I cannot identify. There is a character in the movie that does some translation for the protagonist, but she only translates one or two sentences and not literally. Most of Margu's lines are just unintelligible for the protagonist (and all the audience that does not speak Margu's language).

I am really curious. She only has a handful lines, so I thought I could ask here. What does Margu say to Jasper?

Comment: I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/dws9et/official_discussion_klaus_spoilers/f89tu4c/) but I am unsure of its authenticity

Comment: @fez while that is not official it is quite good. I think it coud do for an answer, as long as you make it clear that it is not official.

Comment: After a bit of looking into the user they seem to actually be Sami, so I will post the above as an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This answer is not official, and is from a translation made from a user on Reddit. I do not know if it is correct without access to the movie and/or the script. But the user in question, [pi-roh-ghee](https://www.reddit.com/user/pi-roh-ghee/), appears to be [Sámi, currently living in Norway](https://www.reddit.com/r/23andme/comments/cvlkvr/my_results_finally_arrived_sami_in_norway/).

From this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/dws9et/official_discussion_klaus_spoilers/f89tu4c/) the translations of each Sámi line is as follows:

- 39:10: Can I get a toy?
- 39:22: Could I also get one, please?
- 54:04: Hello postman
- 54:12: Can you speak with me now, then?
- 1:00:00: I have waited for (so) long
- 1:00:10: Are you going to help me? Finally!
- 1:00:14: I don’t think you understand me
- 1:00:53: You are a dummy
- 1:01:20: I would really like a toy
- 1:01:30 *(difficult to hear over the music, but I think she says)*: I like her, she’s kind
- 1:01:39: I would like a sleigh, a biiig sleigh
- 1:01:46: He’s a little bit of a dummy, right?
- 1:04:29: **(Margu)** - Mom, dad! He came, he came! **(Father)** - Oh, what nice sleigh! **(Mother)**: It’s cold, you should put on your hat. And don’t sleigh too fast
- 1:04:41: This is how you sleigh *(difficult to hear)*
- 01:10:48: It was he who helped me
- **(Father)** - We heard that you might need help
- **(Mother)** - Thank you! You made her so happy
- **(Father)** - On three! One, two, three!
- 1:12:58: Oh gosh, it barely fits (something) he is a big man
- 1:15:06: What is happening?
- 1:17:26: Jesper! Don’t go, Jesper! Jesper, (I don’t understand)
- 1:18:00: You know that I can’t understand you yet, right?
- 1:18:31 **(Man)** - Good! That was the last present... be careful, be careful! Take it very slowly
- 1:18:49 **(Woman)** - Why are they here?

Again, I cannot determine if the above is true and factual. It is from a Reddit thread, from someone who is apparently Sámi, and currently cannot be authenticated.

---

As an additional tidbit of info I found, apparently the director [Sergio Pablos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergio_Pablos) initially intended the character of Margu to be English, but [changed her character to be Sámi and traveled to Norway](https://www.polygon.com/2019/11/15/20966847/netflix-klaus-sergio-pablos-interview-despicable-me). They also could not communicate because Margu ([Neda Labba](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm10520267/)) couldn't speak English, and Sergio could not speak Sámi, and this influenced the relationship between Margu and Jesper in the final film.

Comment: The above translations are quite right, not fake (I know her language and another Sami lg, too, and I teach in that lg). The language Márgu and her relatives speak is North Sami.